# Routing pages in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Working on simple testing application, 
and it's making me soo much furious, Why it's not routeing the pages
For me its seem every thing is fine and good but y I cant see the about page and contact page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
```

** app.js**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('fjapp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/about.htm',
                controller: 'aboutControler'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                controller: 'contactController'
            });
    });

    app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Welcome to the home page";
    }]);

    app.controller('aboutController',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Ok, now you are in About page";
    }]);

    app.controller('contactController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Here find all the contact information";
    }]); 
})();
```

What I am missing..

Comment: Call a function on ng-click, then use $state.go() inside the function

Comment: stick with the normal way of routeing.

Comment: @faisal can you try to use href="#!yoururl" for example "#!about"

Comment: fortunately, my code is same as like this, but for sure I am missing something, that y it's not working. https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `/` in the `a` tag.  It should go like this:

```
<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

**UPDATE**

Include `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` to your `app.config`.
Here is a working 
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/S46KXgOAcaMNi4u4a01F?p=preview)

Comment: inlcude `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` to your `app.config`.  I updated the answer

Comment: and make sure you are using directive `ng-app`

Comment: yes, this is due to the angular 1.6 update. $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); this fix issue

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this

**Html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goto('main')">Main</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.goto = function(pState){
   $state.go(pState);
}
```